# How can I create a link that I can give to someone which creates a copy of a Google Sheet, which based off of an existing sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, links

So I'd like to give my customers a link which they can click on. When they click on it, it automatically creates a new Google sheet which is based off of a template I've created.

Down the line I'd like to create a function with a 'submit order' button which gives me a notification of some sort.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the end of the sheet URL where it says `/edit` or `edit#gid={123456}` with `/copy` it will directly show them a page allowing them to make a copy of the template.

[image]